# Simplify complex fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working to simplify the equation 1+(1/x) divided by 1-(1/x), but i didnt get it. The solution given was to multiply by x/x and the answer is 1+(2/x-1)

My solution was:

(a) 1+(1/x) = (x+1)/x
(b) 1-(1/x) = (x-1)/x
(c) [(x+1)/x]/[(x-1)/x] is the equivalent of multiplying the reciprocal. I get (x+1)/(x-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well those are the same! $$\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}=\dfrac{x-1+2}{x-1}=\dfrac{x-1}{x-1}+\dfrac{2}{x-1}=1+\dfrac{2}{x-1}.$$